# i have an xml stream which is returned from rest service , still cant parse nodes values

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms

```
List<first_table> mylist = new List<first_table>();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse( xmlstream);

foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("first_table"))
{
    first_table ft = new first_table();
    ft.userName = item.Element("userName").Value.ToString();
    ft.userPassword = item.Element("userPassword").Value.ToString();
    ft.userMobile = item.Element("userMobile").Value.ToString();

    mylist.Add(ft);
}

// Binding listview with server response  
return mylist;
```

here is my xml stream such

```
<ArrayOffirst_table>
    <first_table>
        <userMobile>mval1</userMobile>
        <userName>nval1</userName>
        <userPassword>pval1</userPassword>
    </first_table>
</ArrayOffirst_table>
```

the code above doesnot return any value , I tried to bind the list to data grid view and show all list values but all were null. I put the code on async await function still no values returned

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Is `foreach` loop executing?

Comment: Have you considered marking your class `first_table` as serializable and let the framework handle the xml for you?

Comment: the class first_table is from my wcf service and no i didnot mark it as serializable, how can i do that , thanks already

Comment: A stream you use Load() (not Parse). XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( xmlstream);  You only use Parse with a string.

Comment: If `first_table` is a class generated from your WCF Service Reference it will already be marked as serializable. Can you show the code of this class? I suspect you are over-complicating things here.

Comment: i didnot generated the class first_table its just auto-generated when i used linqtosql its the according class for my already created table in sql server [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.first_table")]
 public partial class first_table
 {
  
  private string _userName;
  
  private string _userPassword;
  
  private string _userMobile;

Comment: my xmlstream is string too, i think that i need a library like newton library  to de-serialize my xml result coz i use many xml datatypes and not result happened